# default body margin, I didn't set, but it does have default value 8px, how can get this value?

Tags: html, default, margin

```
    <style type="text/css">
        fieldset {
            border: solid 1px orange
        }
        .label {
            font-family: Arial;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold
        }
        .groupName {
            font-family: Segoe UI;
            font-size: 16px;
            color: Gray
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sap.common.globalization.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sap.riv.base.js" base-url="modules/"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="modules/main.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/sap.riv.themes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="chart" style="width: 600px; height: 400px; background-color: #ffffff"><div id="0" style="position: absolute; font-size: 10px; box-sizing: border-box; overflow-x: visible; overflow-y: visible; left: 8px; top: 8px; width: 600px; height: 400px; ">`
```

In chrome I can see

```
 body{
 display:block;
 margin: 8px;
}
```

I use document.getElementsByTagName('body').style but get nothing.

my first div located at top&left: 8px of the html body.

But it does have margin, how could I get this default margin value?

Comment: The browser margin? Are you trying to remove this margin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a look at the following link :

http://javascript.info/tutorial/styles-and-classes-getcomputedstyle

Check body margin value ( http://jsfiddle.net/eMnBL/6/ ) :

```
var computedStyle = window.getComputedStyle ? getComputedStyle(document.body, null) : document.body.currentStyle;

alert(computedStyle['marginTop']);
```

Comment: doesn't work on FF and IE, works in Opera and Chrome

Answer (score 3):

`document.getElementsByTagName('body')` returns an array on success.
To get rid of the margin in the body use normal css

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

EDIT:
I found this function that can give you the styles of elements on [quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)

```
function getStyle(el,styleProp)
{
    if (el.currentStyle)
        var y = el.currentStyle[styleProp];
    else if (document.defaultView && document.defaultView.getComputedStyle)
        var y = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(el,null).getPropertyValue(styleProp);
    return y;
}
```

[Fiddle1](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/QEPRr/) [Fiddle2](http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/QEPRr/1/)

Comment: sorry to notice you that, I have tried document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style undefined. And I could not change the layout of the page, because I need to get the clientX, and clientY for the position in div chart.